# Checking if string is in text file is not working

Tags: python, file, iostream

I am writing in python 3.6 and am having trouble making my code match strings in a short text document. this is a simple example of the exact logic that is breaking my bigger program:

```
PATH = "C:\\Users\\JoshLaptop\\PycharmProjects\\practice\\commented.txt"

file = open(PATH, 'r')

words = ['bah', 'dah', 'gah', "fah", 'mah']

print(file.read().splitlines())

if 'bah' not in file.read().splitlines():
    print("fail")
```

with the text document formatted like so:

```
bah
gah
fah
dah
mah
```

and it is indeed printing out fail each time I run this. Am I using the incorrect method of reading the data from the text document?

Comment: You've already `read` the file, so when you `read` it the second time, there is no contents left to read. Get rid of your `print` statement, or use `file.seek(0)`.

Comment: You're reading the file multiple times before closing it. Add `file.seek(0)` after your `print` statement, or store the contents into a variable

Comment: Try this `if 'bah' not in list(file.readlines())`

Comment: @RajanChauhan doesn't change a thing: file is already read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that you're printing `print(file.read().splitlines())`

so it exhausts the file, and the next call to `file.read().splitlines()` returns an empty list...

A better way to "grep" your pattern would be to iterate on the file lines instead of reading it fully. So if you find the string early in the file, you save time:

```
with open(PATH, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip()=="bah":
            break
    else:
        # else is reached when no break is called from the for loop: fail
        print("fail")
```

The small catch here is not to forget to call `line.rstrip()` because file generator issues the line with the line terminator. Also, if there's a trailing space in your file, this code will still match the word (make it `strip()` if you want to match even with *leading* blanks)

If you want to match a lot of words, consider creating a `set` of lines:

```
lines = {line.rstrip() for line in f}
```

so your `in lines` call will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
PATH = "C:\\Users\\JoshLaptop\\PycharmProjects\\practice\\commented.txt"
file = open(PATH, 'r')
words = file.read().splitlines()
print(words)
if 'bah' not in words:
    print("fail")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the file two times.

When you do `print(file.read().splitlines())`, the file is read and the next call to this function will return nothing because you are already at the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

```
PATH = "your_file"

file = open(PATH, 'r')

words = ['bah', 'dah', 'gah', "fah", 'mah']

if 'bah' not in (file.read().splitlines()) :
    print("fail")
```

as you can see output is not 'fail' you must use one 'file.read().splitlines()' in code or save it in another variable otherwise you have an 'fail' message